# Dynamically Set list item Id

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

This seems like it should be really easy, but I cannot get this to work.

I have a collection of strings in my view model that's being outputted as list items :

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" id="genreDropDown">
@foreach (string subject in Model.SuggestSubjects)
{
  <li id="listItem'@subject'"><a onclick="LoadSuggestTitles_BySubject('@subject');">@subject</a></li>
}
</ul>
```

When the page renders I'm seeing the id of the list items are being formatted as :

`<li id="listItem'Mystery'">`

**My question :**

Is there any way I can format the ID without the single quotes, so Razor can still pick up the value and append it to id?

Ultimately I'd like for it to read `<li id="listItemMystery">`.

Comment: Have you tried removing the single quotes around ``@subject``?

Comment: @acfrancis I thought that should work as well, but for some reason it's still outputting it as literally `listItem@subject`.

Comment: Try my updated answer

Comment: @acfrancis That was the cat's pajamas. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
<li id="listItem'@subject'">
```

With:

```
<li id="listItem@(subject)">
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@foreach (string subject in Model.SuggestSubjects)
{
  var id = "listItem" + @subject;
  <li id="@id"><a onclick="LoadSuggestTitles_BySubject('@subject');">@subject</a></li>
}
```